# ODA Profile Store Path for Birt Connection Profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, birt

I'm trying to use the Birt ReportEngine within my Spring project. I've successfully generated a report.rptdesign which works within Eclipse.
Now I want to use this 'report.rptdesign' within my application and generate some kind of output (PDF/HTML, does not matter).
I've added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

into my pom.xml. Futhermore I've added (and manually created) both paths for

```
-Dorg.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\temp\workspace_dtp
-Dorg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity_workspacepath=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\temp\workspace_dtp\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity
```

but I keep getting the error multiple times.

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectivityPlugin log
SEVERE: Error loading connection profile data.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectivityPlugin log
SEVERE: Error saving connection profile data.
```

My report.rptdesign uses a 'db' file in order to connect to my database which is correctly referenced within the report.rptdesign

```
<data-sources>
    <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile" name="DB MySql" id="18">
    ....
    <property name="OdaConnProfileStorePath">C:\workspace-sts\myproject\test\db</property>
    </oda-data-source>
</data-sources>
```

**Update:**
The code I used:

```
DesignConfig config = new DesignConfig();
Platform.startup(config);
IDesignEngineFactory factory = (IDesignEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IDesignEngineFactory.EXTENSION_DESIGN_ENGINE_FACTORY);
IDesignEngine designEngine = factory.createDesignEngine(config);

SessionHandle session = designEngine.newSessionHandle(ULocale.ENGLISH);
ReportDesignHandle designHandle = session.openDesign("myReport.rtpdesign");
ElementFactory designFactory = designHandle.getElementFactory();
designHandle.close();


EngineConfig engineConfig = new EngineConfig();
Platform.startup(engineConfig);
IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
IReportEngine reportEngine = factory.createReportEngine(engineConfig);

IReportRunnable design = reportEngine.openReportDesign(designHandle);
IRunAndRenderTask task = reportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
```

Do I need to put the 'db' file somewhere else? I've tried several locations within classpath etc.

Regards,
Manuel

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the 'Spring' tag on your question? You say your design works inside of Eclipse so presumably it has something to do with your Spring Framework.

Comment: I've added the spring tag, thanks. (But I don't think that this is spring-relevant)

Comment: From birt 4.2 we can setup a relative path for a connection profile store, did you consider this option? Do you start the birt engine from your own java code?

Comment: Yes I did try also the relative path within the 'Data Source'. Yes it's integrated in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection profile store is set as a relative path, you have to provide a resourcePath to the birt engine config, before starting up the Platform. For example:

```
engineConfig.setResourcePath("/myResourcePath");
```

The connection store is searched relatively to this resourcePath.